# ¿Por qué es negativo el bit 32?

Tags: java, binario

estoy revisando el desplazamiento de bits en java pero me parece muy curioso que el bit 32 me de negativo yo asumo que es por el tipo de dato INT(32bits) y que tiene un limite de bytes, pero me ayudaría mucho que alguien me lo aclare.

Por ejemplo:

aqui se desplazo 30 veces osea quedo en el bit 31

```
System.out.println(0B1 << 30);// es 1073741824 en base 10
```

aqui se desplazo 31 veces quedo en el bit 32

```
System.out.println(0B1 << 31);// es -2147483648 en base 10
```

aqui se desplazo 32 veces quedo en el bit 33 ósea paso al byte 5

```
System.out.println(0B1 << 32);// es 1 en base 10
```

Comment: Si el tipo de dato es con signo, el modo que tiene el sistema de indicarlo es usando complemento a 2, y dicho sistema usa el ultimo bit (el msf) para indicar signo.

Comment: a okey el ultimo bit indica el complemento a 2 que según el sistema es la parte negativa, ya me queda un poco mas claro

Comment: Puse " msf" queriendo poner "MSB", y el ultimo bit no indica "que este usando el complemto a 2": en caso de ser un numero con signo, siempre se usa complemento a dos, y en ese caso, el MSB indica si el valor es negativo o no, y en caso de ser negativo, para obtener el número hay que invertir los bits y sumar 1, en caso contrario (ser 0, o sea positivo) no hay que hacer nada.

Comment: si me confundió el msf XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el último bit no representa el signo, es un error hacer ese planteamiento. Si fuera de esa manera, entonces el valor `1` decimal, utilizando 4 bits para simplificar en lugar de 32, se representaría `0001b` y el `-1` se representaría `1001b`, y no es así. El valor `1001b` representa el valor `-7` decimal.

Lo que sucede es que en *complemento-2* los valores negativos se representan tomando el valor positivo, negando todos los bits, y luego sumando `1`. Por ejemplo:

El valor `3`, expresado en 4-bits, binario, es `0011b`. Para representar el valor `-3` se invierten todos los bits, quedando entonces `1100b` y luego se suma `1b`, dando el resultado final que es `1101b`.

Como efecto colateral, todos los números negativos tienen su bit más significativo en valor `1`, y el bit más significativo de tu entero de 32-bits en Java es el bit 31.

El número negativo más grande que se puede representar en *complemento-2* es el que tiene su bit más significativo en `1` y el resto en `0`.

La representación formal para el número negativo de un valor `N` en *complemento-2* es **(2^n)-N**, donde **n** es el número de bits y **N** es el valor a representar.

Comment: entiendo el _complemento-2_ es el sistema que utilizan los números binarios para indicar números negativos de un tipo de dato

Comment: Exacto, es además el más fácil de implementar a nivel de puertas lógicas sin necesidad de tener una ALU (suma) independiente para enteros con y sin signo.