# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre char y unsigned char en c?

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo c yo solo y de momento sabía que es un `char` pero buscando una cosa que necesito hacer me ha salido un tipo de variable que se llama `unsigned char` y no entiendo la diferencia. Si alguien me la pudiese explicar se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas son variables de 8bits. La diferencia es el rango de operación que tiene cada uno.

`char` es una variable con signo, que tiene un rango de [-128,127].

`unsigned char` es una variable sin signo, que tiene un rango de [0,255].

El bit de mayor peso (MSB) es el que marca la diferencia. Para variables con signo, si dicho bit es '1', entonces se trata de un número negativo.

```
char variable_con_signo =           0b 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1; // esto vale -1
unsigned char variable_sin_signo =  0b 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1; // esto vale 255
//                                    | |
//                                   /   \
//                                    MSB
```

Por ejemplo,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char variable_con_signo = 127;
   unsigned char variable_sin_signo = 127;

   printf("%d\n", variable_con_signo);
   printf("%d\n", variable_sin_signo);

   variable_con_signo++;
   variable_sin_signo++;

   printf("%d\n", variable_con_signo);
   printf("%d\n", variable_sin_signo);

   variable_con_signo++;
   variable_sin_signo++;

   printf("%d\n", variable_con_signo);
   printf("%d\n", variable_sin_signo);

   return 0;
}
```

La salida de este programa será:

```
127
127
-128
128
-127
129
```

Esto sucede porque al incrementar en 1 la variable con signo, el valor binario en complemento a 2 de esta variable es 0b10000000, que es -128 en decimal. Por otro lado, al incrementar en 1 la variable sin signo, el valor binario de esta variable también es 0b10000000, pero al tratarse de una variable sin signo su valor decimal es +128.

Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la teoría básica de tipos de datos [aquí](https://ccia.ugr.es/%7Ejfv/ed1/c/cdrom/cap2/cap24.htm)

**CONSEJO:**
Si tienes un programa que sólo va a trabajar con números positivos es recomendable utilizar variables sin signo (`uint8_t, uin16_t...`) para tener el mayor rango posible. En cambio, si tu programa necesita variables con valores negativos deberás usar variables con signo (`int8_t, in16_t...`).

Comment: El bit más significativo no indica el signo, es un error decirlo así. Sí coincide que los que tienen ese bit en `1` son negativos para `char`. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/453244/228368) hay más detalles que permiten comprenderlo.

Comment: Por eso he dicho en complemento a 2.

Comment: Claro, pero la frase *El bit de mayor peso (MSB) es el que marca la diferencia. Para variables con signo, si dicho bit es '1', entonces se trata de un número negativo.* induce a un error de interpretación a los noveles porque donde el MSB marca la diferencia e indica el signo es en el Complemento a 1. En Complemento a 2 el hecho de que el MSB esté en valor `1` es sólo una característica común, y no quiere decir *per se* que ya el valor del número sea el negativo del valor representado por el resto de los bits. `-4` y `4` difieren no sólo en el MSB. `-128` y `128` son sólo un caso especial.

Comment: Quizá me haya explicado mal. Cuando me refiero a que el MSB "marca" el signo en un dato _signed_ me refiero a que una variable que tome un valor negativo va a tener el bit de mayor peso a '1' cuando se represente en complemento a 2. Para el ejemplo que marcas: `+4 -> 0b00000100` y `-4 -> 0b11111011`. Obviamente el resto de bits van a ser diferentes dependiendo del número. Tan solo lo quería dejar como apunte.

Answer (score 1):

El tipo char se utiliza para representar caracteres individuales. Por tanto, el tipo char requiere sólo un byte de memoria. Cada tipo char tiene una interpretación como entero equivalente, de esta forma un char es una clase especial de entero pequeño. En la mayoría de los compiladores el entero tipo char puede tomar valores entre 0 y 255. También se puede utilizar datos unsigned char (con valores de 0 a 255) o datos signed char (con valores de -128 a 127).

Comment: Muchas gracias ☺. me has ayudado mucho.